# Access or send a local file to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, heroku

I've got a local .csv file with updated user data that I want to run a simple one-time script on in production (on Heroku, Rails 4 app).  It's open source, so I can't just include the file in the repo without exposing the data.  I'd like to be able to do it from the CLI but can't seem to figure it out.

There's probably a better solution, but I've been trying unsuccessfully to set the contents of the file (which isn't huge) to an environment variable on Heroku.  My Bash skills are weak...

```
$ heroku config:set MY_CSV=<./my_local_csv_path.csv
```

didn't work -- it will not set anything. (running `$ heroku config` shows the env variable blank -- `MY_CSV:`).

Is there a better way to make this .csv file accessible to a script on Heroku?  I suspect it's a similar problem to just accessing the local filesystem from the Heroku console.

Comment: Why can't you just upload the file? I'm not sure what open source has to do with it.

Comment: @mipadi I'm assuming you mean including the file in the repo, in which case sensitive user data would be exposed.  Is there another way to upload a file to Heroku without including it in the repo?

Comment: If the sensitive data is uploaded to Heroku, why would keeping it out of the repo improve security?

Comment: You could always upload it to S3 or other online storage.

Comment: @Fred I'm assuming that if I can keep my private keys in environment vars then Heroku is storing them securely so it's also secure to send a file up there too. Am I mistaken in that assumption?

Comment: How automated does this need to be? Assuming you really do mean **once**, just firing up a Rails console on Heroku seems like the obvious and simple solution. Upload the CSV somewhere, run your job (pulling the CSV in from the network), delete the CSV. Done. Alternately, tweak your script so MY_CSV is a URL and have the script grab it.

Comment: @mmichael, colinm -- It's just a one-off so that's what I actually ended up doing.  Hosted briefly on S3 and pulled it in.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

I just did something similar to what you are doing where the user uploads a CSV for processing in my app. I am also hosting on heroku. Check out...

http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

Basically let your model doing your processing for you that way you don't have to store any files on heroku.

Comment: I'm only looking to access the file once (as an administrator, not a user) to update some user data that got out of alignment due to a dumb mistake, so building out that functionality would be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the heroku cli `-e` flag. It has to be a relatively small file. (all arguments combined are limited to 32kb)

It goes something like this:

```bash
# gzip and base64 encode the file
# (without the encoding, the gzip characters break this argument)
FILE_CONTENTS=$(cat /path/to/file.csv | gzip -fc | base64)

# Pass the variable from above to the dyno above.
heroku run -a APP_NAME -e "FILE_CONTENTS=\"$FILE_CONTENTS\"" rails c
```

Then in your console, you can get the csv by running:

```rb
csv_contents = ActiveSupport::Gzip.decompress(
  Base64.decode64(
    ENV['FILE_CONTENTS']
  )
)
```